# sed: insert text after Nth character preceding/following a given string

Tags: sed

Using `sed`, how would one insert text after a character that precedes (or follows) some string by `N` occurrences. As an example, suppose that the line of text to be edited is the following:

```
command -some -args -c 'a quoted section;some;lines;of code;keyword;more lines;etc();'
```

After finding this line in a text file (perhaps through the unique string `command`), I wish to insert text after the second (N=2) semicolon before `keyword` (i.e., the semicolon separating `lines` and `of`). I would specifically like to use `sed` for the purpose.

Continuing with this example, the expected output would be:

```
command -some -args -c 'a quoted section;some;lines;INSERTED_STRING;of code;keyword;more lines;etc();'
```

where `INSERTED_STRING;` (provided to sed, e.g., via a shell variable) was inserted at the desired position.

Comment: Can you give examples with real inputs and desired outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I perfer it simple:

```
sed '/command/s/[^;]*;keyword/INSERTED_STRING;&/'
```

to insert two fields before the keyword. The general solution would be

```
sed "/command/s/\([^;]*;\)\{$N\}keyword/INSERTED_STRING;&/"
```

but note that the `N` has an offnet of 1 compared to your question: Here, `N=2` means to have two fields between the insert and the `keyword`.

Explanation: `/command/` selects only lines with `command`, so other lines remain untouched. `([^;]*;\)` matches one field (a sequence of non-semicolons) including the following semicolon. By following it with `\{$N\}` the pattern matches `$N` fields. The following `keyword` completes this to match `keyword` and the `$N` fields before. The replacement pattern consists of the inserted string and `&`, which gets replaced by everything that was matched (so in the end, it wasn't a replacement, but an insert).

Shorted, and better readable with extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E "/command/s/([^;]*;){$N}keyword/INSERTED_STRING;&/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you could change only third occurrence of your pattern which is semicolon here.

```
sed 's/;/;INSERTED_STRING;/3' <<<"$string"
```

**Edit:**
To replace N<sup>th</sup> occurrence of a string before another specific *Pattern String* `keyword` ("relative occurrence", in your case 2<sup>nd</sup> occurrence) if lines matched with uniqe `command` string.):

```
sed -r '/command/ s/([^;]*;){1}keyword/INSERTED_STRING;&/' <<<"$string"
```

Comment: 1) Surrounding the whole pattern with `()` and using `\1` is not neccessary. You should use `&` in the replacement instead. 2) Where is `N` in your answer? What to do for `N=42`?

Comment: @Philippos corrected. that's because OP was asked for second and I was stated 2nd in his case so I didn't add unnecessary `{1}` there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see the `;`-delimited bits as fields of a record, you could do this with `awk` like so:

```
$ awk -F';' -vOFS=';' -vstring="NEW TEXT" '{ $4 = $4 ";" string; print }' file
command -some -args -c 'a quoted section;some;lines;of code;NEW TEXT;keyword;more lines;etc();'
```

`awk` would, with `-F';'`, break the line in `file` down into a number of `;`-delimited fields.  The code would then modify the fourth such field by appending an extra `;` and the string held in the variable `string` (defined on the command line), and output the data with the modified field.  The output would likewise be `;`-delimited.